# SimpleXML Returns 0 Element

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm taking my response from a Soap Request, and passing it into a new SimpleXML construct.

```
$response = $this->client->$method(array("Request" => $this->params));
$response_string = $this->client->__getLastResponse();
$this->response = new Classes_Result(new SimpleXMLElement($result));
```

If I echo the $response_string, it outputs a proper xml string. Here is a snippet as it's quite long.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body><GetClassesResponse xmlns="http://clients.mindbodyonline.com/api/0_5">      
    <GetClassesResult>
     <Status>Success</Status>
     <XMLDetail>Full</XMLDetail>
     <ResultCount>6</ResultCount>
     <CurrentPageIndex>0</CurrentPageIndex>
     <TotalPageCount>1</TotalPageCount>
     <Classes>
      <Class>
       <ClassScheduleID>4</ClassScheduleID>
       <Location>
        <SiteID>20853</SiteID>
  ....</soap:Envelope>
```

Hoever, when I try to work with this object, I get errors or if I dump the object it outputs:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#51 (0)
```

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: `Classes_Result`? is it equivalent to `var_dump` ? you should echo / `var_dump($result)` instead.

Comment: Classes_Result is a class, which I am passing in a new SimpleXML object. The var_dump is in the Classes_Result class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not actually using `$response_string`, and you have not set `$result` anywhere, which you have passed to `new SimpleXMLElement($result)`.

Perhaps you intend to build a SimpleXML object with the `$response_string` string via [`simplexml_load_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php)?

```
$response = $this->client->$method(array("Request" => $this->params));
$response_string = $this->client->__getLastResponse();
// Load XML via simplexml_load_string()
$this->response = new Classes_Result(simplexml_load_string($response_string));

// Or if you do expect a SimpleXMLElement(), pass in the string
$this->response = new Classes_Result(new SimpleXMLElement($response_string));
```

The `<soap:Body>` element of your SOAP response is namespaced with (`soap`). To loop over it with SimpleXML, you must provide the correct namespace:

```
// After creating new SimpleXMLElement()
var_dump($this->response->children("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"));

// class SimpleXMLElement#2 (1) {
//   public $Body =>
//   class SimpleXMLElement#4 (0) {
//  }
// }
```

To loop over the body:

```
foreach ($this->response->children("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/") as $b) {
  $body_nodes = $b->children();
  // Get somethign specific
  foreach ($body_nodes->GetClassesResponse->GetClassesResult as $bn) {
    echo $bn->ResultCount . ", ";
    echo $bn->TotalPageCount;
  }
}
// 6, 1
```

Comment: Michael - I've used both methods here and both return an object with 0 elements. object(SimpleXMLElement)#44 (0) { } -- I am not 100% sure why. I could use the standard object returned by the soap client, but SimpleXML makes it easier to loop through. Would something with the XML string cause this at all?

Comment: @RichardTestani I see - it's because of the soap namespace. See addition above.